# Unity oscillate between two coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Cube on (0,2,0) and I want it to move on the y axis from 2 down to 1 and then up to 3 back to 1 back to 3 and so on...

Can someone explain me, what to pass in as parameters when using `Mathf.PingPong()`?

I have

```
public virtual void PingPongCollectable(Transform transform, float speed)
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position; // current position
    pos.y = Mathf.PingPong( ? , ? ); // missing parameters, calculate new position on y
    transform.position = pos; // new position
}
```

so where do I have to pass in the speed and the coordinates A (above) and B (below) ?

The cube should just smoothly slide up and down in a loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the **Mathf.PingPong** method is the following one :

```
public static float PingPong(float t, float length);
```

*PingPongs the value t, so that it is never larger than length and never smaller than 0. 

The returned value will move back and forth between 0 and length.*

The first parameter should be [Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) if you want a smooth transition. 
 The second parameter is the max value. The method then gives you a position between 0 and that max value. 
You can then set a bottom floor and a length for the ping-pong method.

Here is an example using the code you provided :

```
public virtual void PingPongCollectable(Transform transform, float speed)
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    float length = 1.0f; // Desired length of the ping-pong
    float bottomFloor = 1.5f; // The low position of the ping-pong
    pos.y = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time,  length) + bottomFloor;
    transform.position = pos; // new position
}
```

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html

Comment: using `Mathf.PingPong(Time.deltaTime,  length - bottomFloor) + bottomFloor` is not correct. the cube instantly jumps to 0 and moves to 3 and back to 0. but it should move from 1.5f to 2.5f.

Comment: I edited my example. If you want to move between 1.5f and 2.5f, you can do this :
`Mathf.PingPong(Time.deltaTime, 1.0f) + 1.5f`

Comment: You need to use `Time.time` as in the example in the docs, or accumulate the time in a member variable.  `Time.deltaTime` will generally not increase over time so you'll get the same position frame after frame.